# ArrayFormula in VBA using Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

This array formula works just fine if entered using ctrl sht enter:

```
={IF(ROWS(A$7:A7)>A$4,"",IF(SUMPRODUCT((consumers=$A$6)*(data=A$5)*(data=A$5<>""))>0,INDEX 
(employees,SMALL(IF(((consumers=$A$6)*(data=A$5)*(data=A$5<>"")),COLUMN(Data!$B$2:$AC$2)-COLUMN 
(Data!$B$2)+1),ROWS(A$7:A7)))))}
```

I did some research and read that I would have to use the R1C1 notatation if I wanted to use this formula in VBA ... so this is what I have thus far:

```
Sub frmarry()
   Range("y28").Select
   Selection.FormulaArray = "=IF(ROWS(R28C25:R28C25)>R26C25,"",IF(SUMPRODUCT((consumers=R27C25)* 
   (data=R24C7)*(data=R24C7<>""))>0,INDEX(staff,SMALL(IF(((consumers=R27C25)*(data=R24C7)* 
   (data=R24C7<>"")),COLUMN(Data!$R2C2:$R2C29)-COLUMN(Data!R2C2)+1),ROWS(R28C25:R28C25)))))"
End Sub
```

Now, when I run the routine I get a flag:

```
  'unable to set the FormaulaArray property of the Range class'
```

and if I select debug, it highlights the above arrayformula.

I just used the excel setting to set my formula to R1C1 notation so maybe something went astray in the conversion. Since I am not to conversant with R1C1 notation I was hoping someone more conversant with R1C1 would help me resolve this issue or point me in a direction so I can troubleshoot this VBA issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The array formula gives me an error when I enter it into an excel sheet. seems like you are missing something?

Comment: Try it without the dollar sign in the VBA Array Formula

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout ... I just realized that I have two different arrayformulas listed ... one pointing to A7 and the other to Y28 ... but I belive the arrayformula itself is correct.

Comment: Thanks ... I just removed the $sign and the problem still persists.

Comment: I have posted the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This works

```
Sub frmarry()
    Range("Y28").FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(ROWS(R28C25:R28C25)>R26C25,"""",IF(SUMPRODUCT((consumers=R27C25)*" & _
    "(data=R24C7)*(data=R24C7<>""""))>0,INDEX(staff,SMALL(IF(((consumers=R27C25)" & _
    "*(data=R24C7)*(data=R24C7<>"""")),COLUMN(Data!R2C2:R2C29)-COLUMN(Data!R2C2)" & _
    "+1),ROWS(R28C25:R28C25)))))"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow ... thanks for your help ... it is a little staggering to see a solution so quick and then not even understand it:) I guess I understand the """" but I do not understand what the & Chr(10) is doing? Thanks.

Comment: I have removed those. That is for line continuation in the formula bar. Removed it to avoid confusion. Whenever in doubt, record a macro ;)

Comment: Thanks again. Just a quick question on this ... in my first array formula you will see that I have Rows(A$7:A7) locked ... how do I lock the R1C1 notation?

Comment: Got it ... I just switched my spreadsheet over to R1C1 notataion and saw the conversion ... R7C ... and that is the lock ... again thanks.

Comment: Yup. You might also want to read up on this http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/04/29/what-are-a1-and-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel/